# Admits the following description

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests, mathematics

I have a question about the sentence "The evolution of a process
 admits the following description". I checked then the phrase "admits the following description" in Ngram Viewer and found no occurrence. Neither did I found for "allows the following description". Is there something wrong with them?
In case it is, what are appropriate substitutions?

Comment: Don't expect Ngrams to find occurrences of all grammatical phrases; the graph flatlines if there are two few of them to make a good chart of the fluctuations in frequency over time. There are a number of Google hits for both these phrases, and I see nothing wrong with either of them.

Comment: The construction of _admit_ with a situational subject and a descriptional object is just one (fairly formal) way to provide a description of a situation. Quite often there are several possible descriptions available, and one finds phrases like _this admits (of) several explanations/descriptions: ..._

Comment: @John: I was just about to comment that I personally would probably include ***of*** in most instances of this construction - perhaps precisely *because* it's a relatively formal/uncommon usage for most contexts (the preposition makes it easier to recognise as something of a "stock phrase" only loosely related to the more common *admit = confess* sense).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The definitions for _admit_ that have the meaning here ("allow the possibility of") all seem to be intransitive. That would seem to therefore require the "of" or a similar prepositional phrase to specify what they allow...or am I reading too much into the intransitiveness?

Comment: @JeffSahol: Well clearly they don't "require" the ***of*** (that's why John put it in brackets). But if the preposition *is* present, it inevitably follows that the usage admits of no other interpretation than the one under consideration here. Anyway, according to NGrams, [both forms seem to be about equally common these days](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+admit+a+solution%2Cnot+admit+of+a+solution&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20admit%20a%20solution%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20admit%20of%20a%20solution%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: But really, why would one want to write that instead of, "the evolution of a process can be described as follows..."?

Comment: @Jim: Because the _admits of_ construction is archaic and therefore falutes higher. This is academic or legal prose style we're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with that phrasing.  I agree with John Lawler's comment that it is formal, or possibly stilted speech, but still correct.  I would suspect that the usage might flow out of trying to passive tense.

Substitutions I might use:

- (can be | is) described as follows
- fits this description
- may be defined as (though a definition is admittedly stronger than a description)
- has been defined as (followed by citations, if the work is not original)